# How to serialize initialized object in Python into XML?

Tags: python, xml, serialization, deserialization, python-generateds

I am pretty new to python. I now how to marshall/unmarshall objects in Java.
I am looking for something like we did it in Java.
Like:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.Request1.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(message)));

                requestStr2 = (com.Request1) unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc);
```

Where Request1 has @XmlRootElement annotation.

I don't want to write multiple elements, subelements etc, because i have very complex xsd structure. I want to generate classes from xsd by generateDS, then initialize it from database and serialize to xml-file

I saw pyxser, but it is only on python 2.
What modules could help me with that?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use XML? If not then maybe the built-in `pickle` module could help you?

Comment: @TomDalton, yeah i have to in some applications..

Answer (score 0):

The [generateDS](http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html) generated python-modules can parse a XML instance of XML Schema from file or from string. The generateDS module supports complex XML Schemas including complex types, abstract types, enumerated lists, mixed content, etc.

For example, here is the command for generateDS to generate a python module called *people.py* from *people.xsd*.

```
python generateDS.py -o people.py people.xsd
```

On Windows, there is a generateDS.exe wrapper that can be called as a short-cut:

```
generateDS.exe -o people.py people.xsd
```

This is an example XML instance conforming to the *people.xsd* schema.

```xml
<people xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <person id="1">
        <name>Alberta</name>
    </person> 
    <person id="2">
        <name>Bernardo</name>
    </person> 
    ...
</people>
```

The following is a snippet of python to parse the above XML instance in file named *people.xml* that conforms to the XML Schema. The parse() function parses the XML document from a file and creates object structure for classes associated with the elements.

```python
import people as p
people = p.parse("people.xml", silence=True)
# iterate over each person in the collection
for person in people.get_person():
    print(person.name)
```

If wanted to parse from a string variable `xml` then call the parseString() function on it.

```
people = p.parseString(xml, silence=True)
```

Note if the XML content contains encoding declaration then must use bytes input such as doing the following.

```
people = p.parseString(str.encode(xml), silence=True)
```

See [tutorial](http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html#the-xml-schema-input-to-generateds) for details (and more examples) to create a python module from an XML Schema.